# Must I ignore this Laravel directory?

Tags: laravel

I see this directory in the Laravel framework :

> bootstrap/cache

Because the name "cache", I wonder if this directory must be added in my .gitignore (just a curiosity question)?

[image]

or definitely not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This directory is already ignored by default, via [the `bootstrap/cache/.gitignore` file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v6.12.0/bootstrap/cache/.gitignore).

(Your text editor may simply not display `.gitignore` or other dot-files, but this file has been in Laravel by default since 2015. If it's not there, put it back. )

Answer (score 0):

**According to GitHub there is already a Pre-defined Ignore file:**

```
# Laravel 5 
bootstrap/cache/
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env
```

Comment: thanks for your very quick answer . I have not .git in this directory. Strange ? I have upgraded the project from L5.5 => L6.12.0. Do you think I must add it ?

Comment: @Dom The `.gitignore` file in `bootstrap/cache` has been default in Laravel since 2015. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/4e0b15fba1c997405926049d683e25c2101ceb9f#diff-23d455c7f67daf179c04daa026401864 It's definitely there in Laravel 5.5. Remember, your text editor may hide `.gitignore` files (and anything else starting with a dot). Check in the command line, or add a file in there and see if it shows up in the `git status`. I'll bet it doesn't.

Comment: @ceejayoz : bet lost ;-) There is no .gitignore in this directory. I will add it.